# brew linkapps will not link emacs to the applications folder in El Capitan

Tags: homebrew, osx-el-capitan

I have installed emacs by typing `brew install emacs`. It has been installed successfully, but typing `brew linkups --verbose`says:

`No apps linked to /Applications`

Is there a way that I could have emacs in my Applications folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Homebrew** Homebrew has Emacs 24.5. Its a:

A Cocoa-specific Emacs.app can be built using the --with-cocoa switch

To install and link, please run these command in your shell:

```
1. brew update

2. brew install emacs --with-cocoa

3. brew linkapps emacs
```

To start Emacs from the **launchpad** or from **Spotlight**:

```
1. sudo rm /usr/bin/emacs    (removes the older version)
2. sudo rm -rf /usr/share/emacs
```

Or just create an alias in your shell:

```
alias emacs="/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.x/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw"
```

To make it permanent, if using bash, add that line to **~/.bash_profile**.

You could also follow these commands, to install with a Package Manager:

```
1. brew install --with-cocoa emacs

2. brew install --with-cocoa --srgb emacs (to get some colours) 

3. ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/Emacs.app /Applications (for linking)
```

After installation, using the emacs command in the terminal or shell will run the -nw version of Emacs.

Hope this works for you.

Thank you.